# JDBC SQLServerException Parameter not defined

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, playframework

I have a Play 2.4.3 app and using JDBC to connect to SQL Server DB. I just wrote a database class to handle calling stored procedures.  However, I've hit a wall:

The start of my proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WebApp].[Content_GetByAppID]
(
    @inAppID            int,
    @inContentGroupID   int = null,
    @inContentTypeID    int = null,
    @inContentStatus    char(1) = 'A'
)
AS
```

Here's the class method I wrote that prepares the statement:

```
private CallableStatement createStatement(Connection inConnection, String inProc, DataMap inParams) throws SQLException{
    CallableStatement statement = inConnection.prepareCall("{call" + inProc + "}");

    if( inParams != null ) {
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> e : inParams.entrySet()){
            String name = e.getKey();
            Object value = e.getValue();

            if( value != null ){
                if (value instanceof Timestamp){
                    // Sql does its own time conversion.  Let's avoid that
                    statement.setTimestamp(name, (Timestamp)value, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")) );
                } else {
                    statement.setObject(name, value);
                }
            } else {
                // Pass in Special SQL NUll type if parameter is null
                statement.setNull(name, Types.NULL);
            }
        }
    }
    return statement;
}
```

And I make the call with this:
    DataMap params = new DataMap();

```
    params.put("inAppID", Play.application().configuration().getInt("richfoods.app.id"));
    params.put("inContentTypeID", typeID);
    params.put("inContentGroupID", groupID);
    params.put("inContentStatus", status);

    List<Content> content = mgContentDB.getList(
            "WebApp.Content_GetByAppID(?,?,?,?)", 
            params);
```

Whenever the statement variable in `createStatement` tries to set the parameters, I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter inContentTypeID was not defined for stored procedure .

Any ideas whats causing this?

EDIT:  I think the interesting thing to note is that the error doesn't include the proc name.  It should shouldn't it?  That tells me that it can't find the proc?

Comment: Do you have SQL Connector in your project?

Comment: I am using JDBC

Comment: Have you placed SQL Server connector in your `project/bin` ?

Comment: **Connector or JDBC driver** is used to interact java with the database. You must have that.

Comment: I have JDBC Driver.  I actually took this app over and had to port the project to a new batabase

Comment: You use positional parameter placeholders, and IIRC you may need to set the values by position as well in that case.

Comment: I can't use positional.  I use a hashmap to pass in the params

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: This works with `CallableStatement` in SQL Server. The JDBC driver looks up the parameter position and then delegates to the positional version...

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameter placeholders to the command text, e.g., `{CALL [WebApp].[Content_GetByAppID] (?,?,?,?)}` ...? I just tried it and it worked, even recognizing the parameters by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing whitespace characters:

```
// Your code
inConnection.prepareCall("{call" + inProc + "}");

// Fix
inConnection.prepareCall("{call " + inProc + " }");
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I can't believe I missed that.  Now onto the next problem.

Comment: Hmm, in my testing with sqljdbc42.jar from v6.0.7728.100 both `{CALL mySP}` and `{CALL mySP }` fail, but `{CALL mySP (?,?)}` works (and recognizes the parameter names). Go figure.

Comment: @GordThompson the code in the question did use (positional) parameters.